# Topological and Metric space sequence convergence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Proposition:

In a metric space $(X,d)$, the topological definition of convergence is equivalent to the metric space definition.

My Proof:

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Suppose $\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ $:$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq N$ $\implies$ $x_n \in B(x,\epsilon)$. Let $U$ be an arbitrary open set containing $x$, so by definition $\exists r>0$ $:$ $B(x,r) \subseteq U$.
So by assumption, $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$  such that  for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ whenever $n\geq N$ then $x_n \in B(x,r) \subseteq U$.

For the converse, suppose $\forall U(open)$ $\owns x$ $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ $:$ $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, $n\geq N$ $\implies$ $x_n \in U$.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Consider $B(x,\epsilon)$. As an open ball is an open set, there exists a natural number $N$ such that for any other natural number n satisfying $n\geq N$ we have $x_n \in B(x,\epsilon)$

Is my proof correct? May I have feedback, please?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

To have an answer (so the question does not remain forever unanswered):

Yes, this is correct. In short, a metric open set contains a ball around each of its points so we can apply the $\varepsilon$-definition to the used radius and vice versa open balls are open, so the topological version applies to them.

Next on the list: continuity?